# Jquery - select input value and change it

Tags: jquery

In order to have my Jquery code as clean as possible I'd like to know whether it's possible or not to do the following.

```
$("#button2").click(function(){
        getinput = $("#input2");
        getinput.val("value2");
    });
});
```

The code above is working fine, but imagine I have a function where I just use the #input2 to get / change the value. Doing .val() all the code is a bit messy and if possible I want a cleaner way like:

```
$(function(){
    $("#button1").click(function(){
        getinput = $("#input1").val();
        getinput = "value2";
});
```

That is not working but is the approach I'm looking for.

[JSFIDDLE of the two examples above](http://jsfiddle.net/dDAE9/)

Is there any way to `getinput = $("#input1").val()` and change it by just `getinput = "something"`?

Comment: You don't have to get the value first to change it... it looks like you are just trying to do `$("#input2").val("value2")`? or possibly `$("#input1").val($("#input2).val())`? Your question is unclear to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to change the value in the input just by changing the value of the variable holding the value of the input.

To change the value of the input you must **always** call `.val('foo')` on the input.

Comment: Thanks @mkoryak. I guess I'll have to do it like I wrote in the first method, right?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you'll do it:

```
$(function(){
    $("#button1").click(function(){
        var setinput = "something",
        getinput = $("#input1").val(setinput);
    });
});
```

You're changing what is in the variable and essentially throwing away the whole `$("#input1").val();` part.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't.  `.val()` returns a string, not a jQuery object.

Comment: it doesn't matter what `val` returns, because nothing you assign to any return value will ever change the original thing returned from any function.